# How to find the closest low-rank correlation matrix?

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-rank

Given $n \geq 5$ and a rank-$(n-1)$ correlation matrix $\bf C$, how can I find the rank-$3$ correlation matrix closest (in the Frobenius norm) to $\bf C$?

Comment: Have you tried using the SVD based low rank approximation ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I would like my approximation matrix to be a correlation matrix also. Singular value decomposition of a correlation matrix does not necessarily yield a correlation matrix.

Comment: So, what we need is a low rank approximation matrix from the class of symmetric positive semi definite matrices ?

Comment: Yes but also where if $\hat C$ is the approximation then $diag(\hat C)=(1,1,1,...,1)$

Comment: I could find this paper about "low rank approximation of matrices using cholesky decomposition":http://www.simtech.uni-stuttgart.de/publikationen/prints.php?ID=166 . I don't know how to check if the resulting matrix is a correlation matrix though.

Comment: Originally I was using this correlation matrix of rank $n-1$ to represent a simplex with $n$ vertices, the idea was that the closest rank 3 correlation matrix would be a maximally spread configuration on $S^2$, it turns out that this configuration is a spherical design, cheers.

Comment: Really sorry but I don't have any idea about "configuration","spread",etc. What are your ideas to solve this problem ? Have you looked at thi book : http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447122267

Comment: Are you still interested in this?